# How to create alerts for Watchgurd firewall in SIEM

Tags: siem

I'm working in a SOC (Security Operation Center) where we use a WatchGuard firewall in our customer's environment.

We currently create alerts for other devices (SonicWall,Cisco ASA) based on event codes, and messages. I want to similar create WatchGuard alerts, but my WatchGuard raw logs don't show any event codes.

Can some one please help me in understand how to create alerts for WatchGuard or please provide WatchGuard log guide?

Comment: Welcome to Information Security SE. Is this what you need? [WatchGuard Log Guide](http://www.watchguard.com/support/Fireware_Howto/HowTo_SetupLogServer.pdf) . Your question may belong on a support site, rather than InfoSec SE.

Comment: Hey Jedi.. Thanks for sharing the doc, but which is not am expecting exactly...sample alert in Watchgurd in SIEM or alert policies ..

Comment: You can make rules based on use cases, rather than codes. I.e. alert when X drops happen in X time frame.